# Writing SQLite database query to separate files

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x, pandas

I have the code below which places all the results from my SQL query into the HTML and text documents that are predefined. I want to write them into separate files based on the `messages.conversation_id column` from the database it is working from. Which function could I use to do this? I cannot find any in the research I have done.

Thank you in advance.

```
cur = cur.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT messages.conversation_id
                FROM messages
                INNER JOIN participants_info  ON messages.participant_id = participants_info._id
                WHERE messages.conversation_id IS NOT NULL;""")

query = ("""SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',messages.date/1000,'unixepoch'), participants_info.number, participants_info.contact_name, messages.body, messages.conversation_id, messages.participant_id
        FROM messages
        INNER JOIN
        participants ON messages.participant_id = participants._id
        INNER JOIN
        participants_info ON participants.participant_info_id = participants_info._id
        WHERE messages.conversation_id = ?
        ORDER BY messages.date;""")


with open('messages.html', 'w') as h, open('test.txt', 'w') as t:
for convo in cur.fetchall():
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=convo)

    # HTML WRITE
    h.write(df.to_html())
    h.write('<br/>')

    # TXT WRITE
    t.write(df.to_string())
    t.write('\n\n')
```

Comment: swap the order of your with and for statements, and adapt with open() to have a dynamic file name and not a static name

Comment: How would I assign the SQL query as a dynamic variable? Sorry first time working with SQLite and Python!

Comment: Sure, no worries, comment was here for answer inspiration too and someone actually did it. Check out Nathan's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cur = cur.execute("""SELECT DISTINCT messages.conversation_id
            FROM messages
            INNER JOIN participants_info  ON messages.participant_id = participants_info._id
            WHERE messages.conversation_id IS NOT NULL;""")

query = ("""SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',messages.date/1000,'unixepoch'), participants_info.number, participants_info.contact_name, messages.body, messages.conversation_id, messages.participant_id
    FROM messages
    INNER JOIN
    participants ON messages.participant_id = participants._id
    INNER JOIN
    participants_info ON participants.participant_info_id = participants_info._id
    WHERE messages.conversation_id = ?
    ORDER BY messages.date;""")


for convo in cur.fetchall():
    with open('{}.html'.format(convo), 'w') as h, open('{}.txt'.format(convo), 'w') as t:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conn, params=convo)

# HTML WRITE
h.write(df.to_html())
h.write('<br/>')

# TXT WRITE
t.write(df.to_string())
t.write('\n\n')
```